# How to use Timestamp in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I want a php code that gets the timestamp from a `MySQL database` row (name time) and print it in the form of `DD-MM-YYYY`.

Comment: what did you try/code to solve this yourself? seeing no code makes this question unclear/too broad.

Comment: now read the content

Comment: the question is too broad. There are ample tutorials and manuals out there for you to consult; try something then come back when you have trouble with code, we'll be more than happy to help then. "Too broad" means "there are too many possible answers...".

Comment: ok thanx to help me

Comment: please don't give negative....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :-

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME");
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ){ 
echo date("j-n-Y",strtotime($row["time"])) ."<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Timestamp is stored as part of the record, so let's assume that you are pulling a record from the users table that has 2 columns (created_at, and updated_at).

I'm assuming you're using unix timestamp.

When fetching the records (depending on what method you are using PDO, MYSQLI), you should get an object (we'll call it user)

so, when you have that object, you can simply run this:

```
<?php 
    date('d-m-Y', $user->created_at)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be date('d-m-Y', $user->created_at)? time() just outputs timestamp...

Answer (score 0):

i dont know your mysql server configuration, but you have to connect to your mysql server and have a `$conn` for the connection. Then you can try like this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME"); //YOUR_TABLE_NAME should be changed to your currently db name
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) {
   echo date("j-n-Y", strtotime($row["time"])) . "<br />";
}
```

the output would be something like this:

```
12 - 12 - 2016
 ↑    ↑    ↑
DD - MM - YYYY
```

Comment: @user7285239 check it if it helped :)

Comment: What does it mean

Comment: @user7285239 you can check the answer right there where you can vote my answer

Comment: but you are able to mark it green :) right below the voting

Comment: What does you mean with green, As i m new here, i don't know

Comment: my score of my answer is 0 but below that you are able to click on a grey hook like this ✓